# Changing Old Fan to new light only LED Fixture

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I'm trying to change out an old ceiling fan with a newer light only LED light, but I'm having trouble with the wiring.

Here is a picture of the switch box:
[image]

And here is a picture of the ceiling box:
[image]

Black A is always hot with the breaker on. With nothing connected in the light box (like in the picture), the switch is dead. Red/whitr/black c are also dead with everything in the picture. And that's pretty all I got. Ive tried a couple if things but everything Ive Tried results in either no power to other things or power to red/white/black c always hot weither or not the switch is off or on.

Comment: What is the Poo A and Poo B, is it neutral or ground.

Comment: Do you have separate switch somewhere for the old Fan, and separate for the light.

Comment: @knowitall, yeah I think so. And that is the only switch. It controlled the light and the fan before.

Comment: Why are the wires all spread out like that? How were they hooked up before?

Comment: There are two black wires under a single screw on the switch. There is a 99.999% chance that this is a code violation. Those two black wires should be connected together (with a 3rd, 6" piece of black wire) under a wire nut (similar to what holds the 2 white wires together), then the single 6" piece of black wire should go under that screw.

Answer (score 4):

Connect black A, black B and black C together. Connect Poo A, Poo B and the other white wire together. Poo A and Poo B are really old discolored white or neutral wires. You've now energized the hot going into the switch box and a neutral and also energized that non working outlet.  Take the black wire from your new light and hook it up to the red wire  and the white wire from your fixture to the group of white wire. The double black connection to the switch isn't allowed and you should pigtail them to a single piece of wire and connect that to the switch. There doesn't seem to be a ground wire going up to the switch.

Comment: What about Black C

Comment: Sorry, but still nothing. The red/white/black c are all dead with the switch off or on. Ill edit that in to my post.

Comment: @Ghostship make sure all breakers are on and test at the switch.

Comment: @JACK with nothing connected in the light bix (like in the picture), the switch is dead.

Comment: Were there any other fixtures/outlets without power when every thing was disconnected?

Comment: @JACK  yes there is an outlet that is dead

Comment: @Ghostship  Ok, at ceiling hook black A, black B and Black C together .  hook the three white wires together.  See if the red switches on and off from the switch to the group of neutrals .

Comment: @JACK with 3 black connected to each other and 3 white connected to each other. Red is always hot and outlet is on.

Comment: @Ghostship  Test black to neutral  and red to neutral at the switch

Comment: @JACK not multimeter, just a tester pen. I think its safe to say Im in over my head at this point and should have someone more knowledgeable than me come take a look at it in person. I Have someone that can do that tomorrow. Ill let yiu know what they find out. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Ghostship That could be the problem with the always hot red.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended being connection all 3 black wires to together. All 3 white(Poo = White) together plus the white from the new light fixture, then connection the red to the black from the fixture.

Comment: So my answer was correct.

Comment: This is already listed as an answer.

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what @JACK said in his answer.